# Malformed link at the Ask Wizard's "Show some code" step

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, ask-question-wizard-2018

Notice the non-rendered link labeled "*minimal, reproducible example*":

> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks so much... I got so preoccupied with the *name* of the URL this past week that I forgot to verify that it worked at all.

Link now renders properly:

[image]

...and links to the article's [canonical URL](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well.