# Please reword the Ask Question Wizard's intro for Software Recommendations

Tags: feature-request, new-users, ask-question-wizard-2018, software-recs-se

In the [Ask Question Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard), there are 6 options:

- 3 of these options make a customized message appear. For instance, the "*I have a question about some code*" option's message is a custom message about code, including the tip "*Make sure to have any code handy - including this will help you get fast, quality answers.*"
- 3 of the options have a **generic** message "*Stack Overflow is mainly for code questions, but **<SITE NAME>** is a good place for questions like yours.*"

In particular, here is what people see after selecting the "*I need a software recommendation*" option:

[image: The Software Recommendations community is here to help you with a software recommendation. Tip: Stack Overflow is mainly for code questions, but Software Recommendations is a good place for questions like yours.]

## Problem

The current wording makes it sound like *any* software recommendation question is OK, thus everyday we get tons of [off-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions like:

- "*What protocol do you recommend for a FPS game?*"
- "*Please recommend a tutorial for Spring MVC*"
- "*I want to concatenate two strings in Java, I can use `+` or `concat`, what is your recommendation?*"
- "*Which is best, ImageMagick or GIMP?*"

## Consequence

This vague wording has lead to an explosion of off-topic questions.

The Ask Question Wizard has been active from December 20 to February 19, then inactive, then active since March 23. Whenever it is active, very consistently, we get an [explosion](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/recent-proliferation-of-how-to-code-questions-superuser-questions) of off-topic questions. The analytics show that we get **+1900% of closed questions** when the wizard is active.

We moderators and close-voters are totally overwhelmed:

- We are struggling to do the impossible, but we are close to **burnout**.
- We used to be friendly and comment on off-topic questions, making many of the new users understand the site and become great users. We don't have time to do this anymore.
- The worse is, even though we do our best, many off-topic questions get through, so the +1900% figure above does not even show how bad the situation is.

## Solution

The Ask Question wizard's wording can be improved, a lot. 3 of the 6 options already have a different wording, so it is not like it is technically impossible.

Our small community [brainstormed](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/lets-reword-our-intro-at-the-ask-question-wizard) and here is the wording that got consensus:

## Requested wording

[image]

> Great!
>
> The Software Recommendations community is here to help you find software that matches your requirements.
>
> Tip: Make sure to tell us all of your requirements, as well as your operating system and your budget.

We are aware that the wording change is not a 10-seconds thing and requires testing, but that would greatly help our community, thanks! :-) I am happy to perform testing [as usual](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385363/malformed-link-at-the-ask-wizards-show-some-code-step/385388#385388).

Comment: FWIW, there has been a minor but (supposedly) significant change applied on the AQW, though I don't know when it was changed: that [it's now redirecting to **`/help/on-topic`**](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7676783#7676783) (previously [it redirected to the main index of the `/help` page](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7676685#7676685) and left the askers being lost). However.... looks like it doesn't really help... and I'm sorry but I doubt the request to change this will help if they didn't read anything at all in the first place...

Comment: @NoDistractionWizard: I remember seeing that /on-topic redirect a month ago if I am not mistaken. Unfortunately, the impact seems limited: closed questions broke their all-times-high record 20 days ago, and got another very high peak as recently as 10 days ago.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We're aware that there's some issues with the impact of the Question Wizard on your site (and HW Recs, too, probably). I was hoping the change in the help center URL would do something to better inform people but this or something for new askers before they're able to ask a question... But the impact on the sites that the wizard is pointing people at is definitely something I'm thinking about.

Comment: Predictable: 'the help section clearly defines my question as off-topic but, since I need my answer, that annoying detail can be ignored and I will post anyway'...  :(

Comment: @MartinJames: Such behavior is exacerbated by the current unequivocal wording _"<SITE NAME> is a good place for questions like yours"_. The proposed simple wording modification will definitely make a majority of people think more carefully.

Comment: @Catija The problem with referrals from SO to SoftwareRec not working out of the box is old. For years, migrated questions performs poorly on SoftwareRec without major reworking. Being a bit more explicit about that unspecific software recommendations are off-topic here and there is probably the only thing that makes users aware of it.

Comment: It's not just software recs that the wizard has a dubious signpost to. The wizard tells users that if they want to ask how to "troubleshoot" some "software", they should ask on Super User - without any indication that this refers only to consumer software tools that other people may have used, and not to debugging the asker's code. I previously predicted that *Superuser* mods would turn up on our Meta with tales of a deluge of off-topic code debugging questions and beg us to stop... but apparently it was another Exchange that we caused a crisis for, rather than Super User.

Comment: @Trilarion Sure, it was definitely pre-existing but it was manageable. It went from 5-15 questions closed per week to 100-150+. That's... Um... a bit hard for a site to deal with.

Comment: @Catija I think you missed trilarion's point there. Historically _any_ attempt to direct users to software recs has been problematic unless very explicit and up front about how strict that site is. It would be like another site having an option that says "if your question is about code, then Stack Overflow is the right place for your question."

Comment: I am confident we can make a good Ask Question Wizard that benefits new users without making moderators' lives impossible. The first step is this wording change, the second step is now being discussed on SR meta: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/lets-design-our-own-ask-question-wizard-guide When we have both of these, I am confident that the majority of incoming questions will be on-topic (unlike now).

Comment: The sheer amount of traffic on SO compared to other sites in the network implies that if there's any kind of visible link (let alone a direct path in the wizard) to another site, the small percent of clueless users that click through and ask without reading anything will be a significant burden to the corresponding site. I'm pretty sure we can only fix this if there's no direct link to Software Recs or any other site in the wizard. We're used to the torrent of lazy crap and it doesn't matter if our crap heap is a bit larger, but offloading even a small fraction to small sites is a disaster.

Comment: I think the main issue is the tone of the message saying that the recommended site is definitely the place for their answer. It should be reworded to state that the site *may* be a better place to post their question and should link to the guidance on posting an answer on that site.

Comment: While I'm not an expert on SR, it seems to me that the example questions you included are all fundamentally off topic and including their requirements, OS and budget wouldn't do anything to make them on topic. Are those representative of the problematic questions you're getting? And the change in the primary text seems very minor to me, so I doubt that would change anything. If anything, I'd drop "Tip" (and change the look appropriately), because it's not a tip, it's a requirement.

Comment: I'd probably instead go with something like "Please read through the help center before asking to make sure your question is appropriate and contains all requirements".

Comment: @Dukeling: Yes the examples are representative of what we are getting, and you are right that specifying an OS and budget will not make those on-topic. The current wording encourages such questions, while the proposed wording (particularly the "_Make sure to tell us all of your requirements_" part) does not.

Comment: I agree that "make sure to tell us your requirements" doesn't sound like "please think real hard if your question is appropriate here". It sounds like "yeah, sure, come along, just don't forget to wipe your feet".

Comment: I might suggest an even stronger phrasing such as "Please DO NOT ask a question before checking the help center to see what types of questions are allowed and what information is required in questions". Although I have to say [the "on topic" page of SR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (the first place you end up when clicking the button in the wizard) could really do with some expansion and bullet lists.

Comment: 3 weeks and almost 100 upvotes later, what are the next steps? The problem is as bad as ever, and us moderators are reaching burnout. Is there a kind of roadmap in the company running this site?

Answer (score -14):

Problems:

- Migrating questions have never worked well in the Stack Exchange network, ever.
- *Software recommendations* is a horribly broad and vague name for a site.

What the SO Ask a question wizard should do:

- Explain that general recommendation and opinion-based questions looking for discussion are off-topic.
- Explain that requests about where to find tools, libraries and other off-site resources are off-topic.
- If the poster persists in demanding the latter, the wizard could perhaps re-direct them here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Then leave it at that.

What the softwarerecs community should do:

- The Wizard is only partially to blame. Naming the site *Software recommendations* is to invite a flood ambiguous, opinion-based questions. Such as "how do you recommend that I write my program?" Wizard or not, the crap question problem will ultimately escalate as the community grows.

  Experience from other Stack Exchange sites suggest that you should pick another name ASAP. Or you'll risk ending up in the same dung heap problem that the Programmers and Electronics sites had. Each site is now renamed to Software Engineering and Electrical Engineering respectively.

  One random suggestion: *Software tool recommendations*.

Comment: Do you really suggest showing literally "_General recommendation and opinion-based questions looking for discussion are off-topic. Requests about where to find tools, libraries and other off-site resources are off-topic_"? If not, would you mind adding to the two "Explain" bullets a real wording that you suggest should be actually used? That would allow us to discuss the exact wording. Thanks! About the other ideas (like the name change), they must be considered indeed but better do it in separate posts at https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I have no suggestions for the exact wording. We already have them here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic